# How to include same model relation "parent" in django queryset filter

Tags: django, django-models, filter, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have this scenario:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age =...
    city=...
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(People)
```

I am building a search function that takes the user's criteria into a list of Q filters and returns a queryset of the result.

How do I get the queryset to include the parents for every person that has a parent but the parent does not fit the search criteria?

```
Example:
  Person A - 60 Years old
  Person B - 30 Years old - Parent A
  Person C - 30 Years old
  Person D - 40 Years old

  so now filtering on Age 30, I want the result to show:
  A,B,C since A is a parent of B, rather than just B & C
```

I can flatten the result and get the id's and do a second query for any parents and merge the two query sets.

but is there any way for me to do this in one go within the Q filter function?

Comment: Do you want to filter inside `parent`?

Comment: i have updated the question with an example if that makes it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this with [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

People.objects.filter(Q(age=30) | Q(people__age=30))
```

Or if you use [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in ForeignKey relation, ie: `parent = models.ForeignKey(People, related_name="children")`, then:

```
people = People.objects.filter(Q(age=30) | Q(children__age=30))
```